# Input "placeholder" attribute no longer working in IE when using AntiXssEncoder

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, antixsslibrary

I am unable to see the *placeholder* values on input elements when the input is empty and deselected. The input elements:

```
<input id="OldPassword" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_old" placeholder="Old password" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off" required />
<input id="NewPassword" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="New password" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off" required />
<input id="NewPasswordRepeat" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Repeat new password" tabindex="3" autocomplete="off" required />
```

[image: Placeholders not displayed on input elements]

This issue emerged when I had just upgraded the project from .NET4.0 to .NET 4.5.1 and I had added an *encoderType* to the *httpRuntime*:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" 
             requestValidationMode="4.5" 
             enableVersionHeader="false"
             encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder,System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

When removing the AntiXss *encoderType* attribute, the inputs display their placeholders again:

[image: Placeholders are displayed on input elements]

I only have this issue when using Internet Explorer, Chrome and FireFox seem to be working just fine. I am using *Internet Explorer v11.0.9600.17728*, so placeholder attributes are supported or they wouldn't have worked before using the *AntiXssEncoder*.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by a meta tag for **X-UA-Compatible** with multiple content values for early IE version rendering:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

The contents of this tag were encoded by the *AntiXssEncoder* to

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;&#32;IE=8;&#32;IE=7;&#32;IE=EDGE" />
```

Internet Explorer seems to be unable to work with the **&#32** HTML code in meta tag contents and cuts the value off right after *IE=9*, causing the page to render in compatibility mode for IE9. Support for placeholder attributes was added in IE10, hence why they didn't display since the document was rendered for IE9.

I solved the issue by removing the spaces in the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9;IE=8;IE=7;IE=EDGE" />
```

Comment: Mark as answerd. So someone else won't have to try to find a solution for you.

Comment: I posted this question as [Q&A](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) style, so others may find their solution for similar problems. Unfortunately SO still limits me to accept my own answer after 2 days.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Then don't forget to mark as answered after 2 days. :)

Comment: I will most definitely do!